# fill a 2 dimentional vector

Tags: c++, vector

I have a set of primary vectors now I want to push them back into a 2dim vector, but I am not completely sure how can I assign each primary vector to a 1dimention of 2D vector?

```
vector< vector<int>> V;
 vector<int> p1; 
vector<int> p2;
vector<int> p3;
P1=[0,1,2,3];
p2=[4,5,6,7];
p3=[8,9,10,11];
```

What I want is to fill V as below:

```
V={{0,1,2,3},{4,5,6,7},{8,9,10,11}};
```

Can I do it as below::

```
V.push_back(p1);
V.push_back(p2);
V.push_back(p3);
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: `P1=[0,1,2,3];` Did you mean `vector<int> p1={0,1,2,3};`? Then yes.

Comment: @erenon _'And your question is?'_ Can I do it as below?

Comment: @erenon: I just wanna make sure I am doing it correct. i mean by calling push_back each time it starts to fill next dimension, Am I correct ?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: yes, they are 1D vector , So that's correct? 
THANKS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use separate `std::vector<int>` variables and `V.push_back(p1)`, etc.

Though for simple static initialization this syntax [works](http://ideone.com/QAwAez) at least with c++11:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> V = 
    { std::vector<int>{0,1,2,3}
    , std::vector<int>{4,5,6,7}
    , std::vector<int>{8,9,10,11}
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it this way:

```
vector<vector<int> > V;
vector<int> p1; 
vector<int> p2;
vector<int> p3;

p1 = { 0,1,2,3};
//   ^        ^
p2 = { 4,5,6,7};
p3 = { 8,9,10,11};

V.push_back( p1);
V.push_back( p2);
V.push_back( p3);
```

and the final result will be same as with `V = { { 0,1,2,3}, { 4,5,6,7}, { 8,9,10,11}};`

http://ideone.com/Edxn0O

Answer (score 1):

It will work except you need to replace

```
P1=[0,1,2,3];
p2=[4,5,6,7];
p3=[8,9,10,11];
```

by

```
P1={0,1,2,3};
p2={4,5,6,7};
p3={8,9,10,11};
```

Or you can simply use (under C++11):

```
vector<vector<int>> V = { {0,1,2,3}, 
                          {4,5,6,7}, 
                          {8,9,10,11}
                        };
```